# How do i get rid of the error that occurs while i run my project in web browser?

Tags: deployment, javafx, javafx-8, web-deployment, javafx-webengine

I tried running my project which is in javafx and uses u8.45 jdk. give the error while running in browser. the steps i followed to run my project is simply changing run option provided in Netbean to "Run in browser"

the Error:
`com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource: file:/C:/Users/chirag/Desktop/trunk/User_management_application/dist/User_management_application.jar
    at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.getCommonCodeSignersForJar(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.check(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

please Guide me how to run the project in web browser,

thank you very much.

Comment: You need to sign your application to get rid of this problem. Since, Java 7u51, oracle has made it mandatory for all RIA applications to be signed in order to run it on browser.

Comment: any link which will guide me how to Sign my application ?? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign your application to get rid of this problem. Since, Java 7u51, oracle has made it mandatory for all RIA applications to be signed in order to run it on browser. You can find the complete information in this oracle blog :

[New security requirements for RIAs in 7u51 (January 2014)](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias)

If you want further details on how to sign applications, you can follow :

[Signing and Verifying JAR Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html)